# Adding location data to Google Photos

Tags: google-photos, geolocation

In Google Photos, when I view an individual photo in my web browser and click on the "i" (with a circle around it) to bring up the photo info, at the bottom of the info it says "Where was this taken?"  I click on this and it brings up a dialogue box that says "Edit location" with a space to enter a location.  I enter the latitude and longitude (because there is no close place name and I want to enter exactly where it was taken, not miles away), which I obtained from Google Maps, but nothing happens.  I hit enter to commit the location, and still, nothing happens.  It won't save my location!    If I just close the dialogue, it is still asking me where the photo was taken.

Eventually, I would like to automate this process, as I have GPS data that I can correlate the time the picture was taken to the lat/long I was at at the time.  How can I get Google Photos to accept this information?

Update: One extra reason for wanting to add GPS coordinates is that I have a lot of pictures for which I know the exact address, but for whatever reason, Google Photos refuses to recognize the address, even when I copy it directly from Google Maps!

Answer (score 3):

Google Photos is able to handle only the level 1 locations, therefore you are left with an option to give up on exact coordinates and set up only approximate location.

- ### **level 1:** **`Île Amsterdam`** <sub>(which is: -37.8324742, 77.5359067)</sub>

  [image: 4]
- ### **level 2: `5HG4+RX La Roche Godon, French Southern Territories`**

  [image: 0]
- ### level 3: `-37.822906, 77.557429`

  [image: 5]

You can also try to submit a request for adding this functionality:

[image: 5]